# Adding special characters to the values

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell function which takes values from db. Is there a way to add a $ sign to the value retrieved?

Eg: After the data retrieval, how to add $ sign has to  the values which represent the cost.

```
function ParametersingData {
   param([string]$tablename)

 $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
 $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=servername; Database=dbname; Integrated Security=true"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from $tablename"

$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
try {
      $rowcount = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
} catch [Exception] {
      Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}

return ()
 }
```

The script file is as below:

```
 Data $(ParametersingData "tablename")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a dollar sign to a string, you just add a backtick before the dollar, or use single quotes for the dollar sign to not be interpreted as an expression qualifier. Also, if the dollar sign does not prepend a left brace or a literal, it's not interpreted as a special character and is used literally. An example:

```
$sum=5
"$sum$" # returns "5$"
"`$sum" # returns "$sum"
'$sum' # also returns "$sum"
"$sum`$(`$sum)" # returns "5$($sum)"
"$sum$(`$sum)" # throws exception, Name "$sum" undefined
"$sum$ (`$sum)" # returns "5$ ($sum)"
```

Comment: thanks, but what i want to know is, my value from db is 5000 and what i wanted is $5,000. Is there any way that I can get that?

Comment: This should do: ``"`${0:N0}" -f $sum``. Note that this depends on system cultture: `(Get-Culture).NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator` contains a symbol that will be placed as group separator. If that's a comma, you're lucky, otherwise you'll have to call `Set-Culture` (Win8 and above only) to set it to a culture with a comma as group separator.